# Block Dia Diagram Editor from saving backup copies of files

Tags: dia

Dia Diagram Editor always saves backup files in `.dia~` file. Is there any way to turn this off. It is very anoying, I have to manually delete these files each time I save a change to my diagram.

I went through preferences, but found noting that corresponds.

I have also went through both FAQs:

- http://dia-installer.de/doc/faq.html.en
- https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/Faq

but found nothing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it turned out that [such feature does not exist](https://sourceforge.net/p/dia-installer/support-requests/137/).

As for now, Dia Diagram Editor will always save:

- `*.dia` file (holding current version of the file),
- `*.dia~` file (holding previous version of the file).